# Showing Company Follower Count in ASP.NET Webpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, linkedin-api

I am developing a webpage for a company which needs to show the company's linkedIn follower count. I have no idea how to implement this. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you're asking is more complicated than a simple answer can give.  In order to implement LinkedIn you'll either need to use the REST API or the Javascript API.  The general information on company lookup is [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-lookup-api-and-fields).  In order to get specific fields, you'll also need to understand the [LinkedIn Field Selectors](/documents/field-selectors)/

In the REST API, assuming you have successfully implemented the [OAuth Authentication](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) you would make the following call (this is to get the follower count for LinkedIn, which has an ID of 1337:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1337:(num-followers)
```

In the Javascript API you could do something similar with a Raw call:

```
IN.API.Raw("/companies/1337:(num-followers)")
```

If you're going to be using the LinkedIn APIs from scratch, you should work through our tutorials - we don't have any ASP specific tutorials but there is a good C# example/library linked from our [Libraries and Tools](/documents/libraries-and-tools) page that you can work from.

Comment: It's really irritating that we have to use oAuth just to get the number of followers for our company.